# How to work with Null in summation

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am doing `tot := tot + v_row.SAVINGS;` where `tot` is initialized to 0 and v_row.SAVINGS is initialized to `null`.

Now I using `nvl function` to get value `0` instead of `null` for `v_row.Savings` as I need `0` in summation if there is Null but when I return `v_row`, if summation value shows as 0 then I need to have `null` or `blank space` value in return, how can I do it.

**Note:** I am using this for reporting purpose and so if value of summation is zero then I should show null or blank space in report.

Comment: How about you provide some sample data and your full code?

Comment: sample data would be 0 for tot initally and v_row.Savings are initialized to null value and then am trying to sum it up, basically am using this for reporting purpose if summation value is 0 then I need to show null or blank space in report and not null.

Comment: Is this question clear in first place ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NULLIF(expr1, expr2)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions102.htm) is logically equivalent to

```
CASE WHEN expr1 = expr 2 THEN NULL ELSE expr1 END
```

[NVL(expr1, expr2)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm)

**tot** may be NULL and **v_row.SAVINGS** may be NULL.

- Use NVL to ensure a number is returned for the addition
- Use NULLIF to return NULL if the sum is NULL

It may be more appropriate to coerce the tot to NULL just before you return.

Example:

```
tot := NULLIF(NVL(tot, 0) + NVL(v_row.SAVINGS, 0), 0)
```

Comment: @craig, I wasn't expecting to see it highlighted in the code block.

Comment: This is good, thanks for sharing NULLIF function. All I had to do was to check `nvl(tot, 0)` while returning value so that in summation I always have number and there is not null.

Comment: Also, am assigning tot to a different grand total variable which is summation of jan_tot to dec_tot and so am using nvl to add 0 if there is null for any of jan_tot or feb_tot or mar_tot etc and then am just summing it up and putting total back in the report.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
tot := case when tot + v_row.SAVINGS = 0 then null else tot + v_row.SAVINGS end;
```